# Hive Distinct count over array of maps

Tags: count, hive, words

I am new in Hive and I am trying to count **distinct words_values** from my whole **words** column.

id---------------------------words
435400064446779392  [{"words_value":"i","words_id":"1"},{"words_value":"hate","words_id":"2"}]

Notice that the words column is an array. I have much more rows but this above is to show an example. 
I have tried:

`SELECT words.words_value,count(words.words_value) from T1 GROUP BY words.words_value WITH ROLLUP;`

But it counts in each rows.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The explode UDTF is useful for converting nested data structures into ordinary tables that work with ordinary SQL statements. Since you have an array of maps you would need to use explode twice.

```
select count(distinct value) from
    ( select explode(col) from
            ( select explode(words) from mytable ) subquery1
    ) subquery2
where
    key = "words_value";
```

Comment: Ok thank you Carter Shanklin. I managed to get a more simple format; now it looks like this:
{"id":"435400146256293888","word_id":1,"word_value":"@WOWFakta:"}
{"id":"435400146256293888","word_id":2,"word_value":"Mengonsumsi"}
{"id":"435400146256293888","word_id":3,"word_value":"secangkir"}
{"id":"435400146256293888","word_id":4,"word_value":"yogurt"}
This represents a record and I have 20.000 of those. 
Now I want to count specific words per row. For example:

id       |           word |    count =>

435400146256293888  |yogurt  | 1
Do you have any clue?

Comment: With a simple map you can just select words["id"], words["word_value"]